# Correct way to do Principal Data Analysis in SAS

Tags: sas, pca

I am trying to do PCA in SAS; this is the original code I wrote:

```
  ods output Eigenvalues=EVTABLE Eigenvectors=EVCTABLE;
  PROC factor DATA=REPLACED_PRINCECOMP EIGENVECTORS;
  RUN;
  ods output close;
```

However, when I cross check my results with [python sklearn pca](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html), there is a huge difference in the cumulative explained variance ratio (python produces 90% in the first eigenvector, while SAS produces 5% only).

So I changed the code to follow, adding `METHOD=principal`:

```
  ods output Eigenvalues=EVTABLE Eigenvectors=EVCTABLE;
  PROC factor DATA=REPLACED_PRINCECOMP METHOD=principal COV EIGENVECTORS;
  RUN;
  ods output close;
```

Now the PCA results are back to the same range as the python results (around 90% variance explained in the first eigenvector).

I was wondering what the cause of the difference is? Is it `METHOD=principal`? But I was under the impression that the default method is principal according to the [documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_factor_sect006.htm), that's why I didn't add it in the first place.

Besides, the latter code also has a strange feature. It produces the number of eigenvalues and eigenvectors way less than python's sklearn package PCA does. Is it because I didn't specify the nfactor variable?

Comment: First one uses correlation matrix second one uses covariance matrix instead. If your data is standardized, you should get the same results either way.

Comment: You also do not need `ods output close`.